# Access denied to AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory

Tags: c#, download, filesystems

I have created an application that has an update system, something unconventional:

this application installs and runs from:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Application test
```

the executable is called:

```
searchdata.exe
```

but at some point I came up with the great idea of making an update system that you made up of in the following steps:

1. Click the update button: check if the `update.exe` executable exists.

- if it exists execute immediately, and close `searchdata.exe`.
- it does not exist: download `update.dat` from a url and rename to update.exe.

2. this is the download and progress bar script:

```cs
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            DownloadFileWithProgress("http://test.pro/installer/update.dat", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "update.exe", ProgressBar1, Label4);
        }

        private void DownloadFileWithProgress(string DownloadLink, string TargetPath, ProgressBar Progress, Label LabelProgress)
        {
            int bytesProcessed = 0;
            Stream remoteStream = null;
            Stream localStream = null;
            HttpWebResponse response = null;
            try
            {
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(DownloadLink);
                double TotalBytesToReceive = 0;
                var SizewebRequest = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(DownloadLink));
                SizewebRequest.Method = "HEAD";
                using (var WebResponse = SizewebRequest.GetResponse())
                {
                    var fileSize = WebResponse.Headers.Get("Content-Length");
                    TotalBytesToReceive = Convert.ToDouble(fileSize);
                }
                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    remoteStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                    string filePath = TargetPath;
                    localStream = File.Create(filePath);
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int bytesRead = 0;
                    do
                    {
                        bytesRead = remoteStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        localStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        bytesProcessed += bytesRead;
                        double bytesIn = double.Parse(bytesProcessed.ToString());
                        double percentage = bytesIn / TotalBytesToReceive * 100;
                        percentage = Math.Round(percentage, 0);
                        if (Progress.InvokeRequired)
                        {
                            Progress.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
                            {
                                Progress.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString());
                            }));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Progress.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString());
                        }
                        if (LabelProgress.InvokeRequired)
                        {
                            LabelProgress.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
                            {
                                LabelProgress.Text = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString()) + "%";
                            }));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            LabelProgress.Text = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString()).ToString() + "%";
                        }
                    }
                    while (bytesRead > 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException(response.StatusDescription, "Respuesta del Servidor");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error en DownloadFileWithProgress" + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (response != null)
                    response.Close();
                if (remoteStream != null)
                    remoteStream.Close();
                if (localStream != null)
                    localStream.Close();
            }
        }
```

3. the problem is that I am running with normal privileges, I don't want to have to use administrative privileges, but the execution gives me an access denied error when trying to write the file in the application directory.
4. I appreciate your help with point 3 and if you can see the script I don't know what improvements you can bring me.

Comment: The program files folder you are using is going to require additional privileges by default. You could consider using appdata folder instead where default priviliges should be sufficient.

Comment: @olabacker You can give an answer with an example of how the script would look using `appdata`, I suppose that `update.exe` will also require an code update, since `update.exe` is responsible for downloading the new version of `searchdata.exe`